# Loop for keyword in index and if it was found, append the row to a df. If not found, append empty df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

I have changing `df_x` dataframes in which I sometimes find a keyword (e.g. 'Debt') in the index column and sometimes I don't find it. If it is found, the whole row shold be taken and defined as new dataframe `df_debt`. In case the keyword `debt` is not found in the index column, an empty predefined dataframe `df` shall be taken for `df_debt` instead. Right now the empty data frame `df` is appended every time, even if `df_x` has the keyword 'debt' in the index column.

Can anyone help me to edit the loop below to first search for the keyword, and if it does not exist, only then the empty dataframe gets appended?

`df_x` could look like either of the following two alternatives:

| Breakdown | Year1 | Year2 | Year3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Total Assets | 100 | 110 | 110 |
| Debt | 90 | 85 | 80 |
| Total Net | 100 | 100 | 100 |

| Breakdown | Year1 | Year2 | Year3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Curr Assets | 101 | 111 | 111 |
| Other Assets | 91 | 86 | 81 |
| Total Net | 101 | 101 | 101 |

```py
#empty dataframe df which shall be taken for further processing if the row in the 
#Breakdown index column of df_x is not found 

df= pd.DataFrame(columns=['Year1', 'Year2','Year3'])

for i in df_x:
        if idx.contains('Debt'): 
            df_debt= df_x.loc['Debt']
        else: 
            df_debt= df_x.append(df)
```

Can anybody help me with this?

Thank you.

Comment: In the loop you update `i` but if statement checks `idx`

Comment: Can you include your expected output for a either or both of your provided sample cases?

Answer (score 1):

From what you have described you are over complicating it.  It's a straight forward **mask**.  The commented code for conditional assignment works exactly the same as just a straight assignment.  No looping required.

```
df_x = pd.DataFrame({'Breakdown': ['Total Assets', 'Debt', 'Total Net'],
 'Year1': [100, 90, 100],
 'Year2': [110, 85, 100],
 'Year3': [110, 80, 100]}).set_index("Breakdown")

df_x2 = pd.DataFrame({'Breakdown': ['Curr Assets', 'Other Assets', 'Total Net'],
 'Year1': [101, 91, 101],
 'Year2': [111, 86, 101],
 'Year3': [111, 81, 101]}).set_index("Breakdown")

def debt(df_x):
    mask = df_x.index=="Debt"
    return df_x.loc[mask] #if mask.any() else pd.DataFrame(columns=['Year1', 'Year2','Year3'])
print(debt(df_x))
print(debt(df_x2))
```

#### output

```
           Year1  Year2  Year3
Breakdown                     
Debt          90     85     80
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Year1, Year2, Year3]
Index: []
```

Comment: Thanks Rob. Our df_x can have multiple forms with multiple variations as it is scraped from the web. I don't think I can use a mask then, is that right? Since I don't know what information will be in the df_x

Comment: you can always use the conditional assignment part that is commented out to guarantee the structure of the empty DF.  your code is pseudo-code rather than working code... is "Debt" found in the index or in a named column?  still using a mask will be most performant approach.  looping in pandas is an anti-pattern